# npm install generator-webapp fail

Tags: npm

I have cleaned my run `npm remove ...` and `npm -g remove ...` to remove everything related to `npm`. But I still got below error when I try `npm install generator-webapp`

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.6 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.1 wants yo@>=1.2.0
```

Any idea how to fix it? I searched for a while, and the only suggestion is to clean my `npm` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the npm packages. It is the npm itself. The npm in Ubuntu repository is too old. Use [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) guide to install the latest one, and everything works.

Comment: How does this piece of advice differ from that offered by BlakePetersen? (3 - upgrade NPM to latest version)?

Comment: I tried. I cannot upgrade npm with npm...can you?

Comment: @davidshen84 Be sure you are using "install" instead of "update" to update npm to the latest version. Attempting to update it like a standard package doesn't work.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html#how-do-i-update-npm-

Answer (score 4):

I just ran up against the same problem and after some random kicks and punches, was able to get things working.

Step 1: Remove Yeoman

```
$ npm uninstall -g yo
```

Step 2: Clear NPM Cache

```
$ npm cache clean
```

Step 3: Upgrade NPM to latest version

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

Step 4: Install Yeoman

```
$ npm install -g yo
```

After doing this, things kicked into life. I saw the exact same error so I am confident this will work for you. Also, not sure but step 2 may be optional.

Hope this helps, let me know if you hit any other snags!